# Gatsby pageContext empty in GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm building a dynamic Gatsby site with multiple languages through Contentful. I pass the page's ID in the `pageContext` object in my `gatsby-node.js` to fetch the necessary content on each page, but on the root URL `/` the data inside my `pageContext` object is missing.

In my `index.js`-file, the `pageContext` is empty on the root page `/`, with the exception of the parameter `pageContext.isCreatedByStatefulCreatePages` which is set to `true`. However, for every other page created in `gatsby-node.js` the `pageContext` object appears as it should.

I'm creating my pages in `gatsby-node.js` like this:

```
const baseUrl = locale === "da" ? "/" : `/${locale}/`
console.log(`${baseUrl}${slug ? slug : ""}`)
createPage({
  path: `${baseUrl}${slug ? slug : ""}`,
  component: path.resolve("./src/pages/index.js"),
  context: {
    id,
    slug,
    locale,
  },
})
```

My above `console.log` outputs the following:

```
/virksomhed
/konsulent
/kontakt
/ <-- Page context is empty here
/om-os
/en/company
/en/consultant
/en/contact
/en/
/en/about-us
```

I can see that every page is created. On any other page than the index page ("/") the isCreatedByStatefulCreatePages is set to `false`.

I suspect that Gatsby somehow overrides the "createPage" for the root URL, but I wasn't able to find anything describing it in the documentation.

Anyone who have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Gatsby by default creates a page for every js file in `src/pages`. Try moving your template to some other folder like `src/templates` and adjust the value of `component` in `createPage()` accordingly.

Comment: I removed the index.js from the pages folder and created my page.js in my templates folder instead, which fixed the issue. Thanks!